# R Studio 7 Day Moving Average without functions

Tags: r, average

Trying to write a function(without using r functions) that takes a vector and returns a vector of the same length that is the 7 day average. Ideally if 1:10 were input then the output would be 1.0,1.5,2.0,2.5,3.0,3.5,4.0,5.0,6.0,7.0.

Comment: I don't understand. R is a functional language, practically everything in R is a function. What exactly are the requirements? You can't use `mean()`? Even `+` is technically a function in R. That seems odd. Is there a reason for that? Is some sort of homework assignment or something?

Comment: Yup it's homework.

Comment: Well, then see this post about posting homework questions: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions. Try asking a more specific question rather than asking someone to do the assignment for you.

Comment: It is okay to ask about homework. For one, it would be impossible to stop it all even if we wanted to. Stack Overflow exists to help programmers learn and provide a standard repository for programming problems, both simple and complex, and this includes helping students.

Comment: Yes, it is okay to ask about homework questions but did you read the link which MrFlick shared? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions You need to show an effort from your end first before asking us to help you. You need to include that effort in your post. Right now we don't see any effort from your end.

Answer (score 1):

As @MrFlick pointed out, it is nearly impossible to oblige to the OPs requirement of 'not calling any R function'. This is R  after all.

To quote John Chambers:

“To understand computations in R, two slogans are helpful:

• Everything that exists is an object.
• Everything that happens is a function call."

That said, I tried the assignment:

The `moving_avg()` function takes 2 arguments: a numeric vector `x` and the 'range' of the moving average `range_moving_avg`, and outputs the moving average for that vector:

```
moving_avg<-function(x, range_moving_avg){
        if(!is.numeric(x)){
                stop("x should be numeric")
        }else{
                output<-numeric(length(x))
                for (i in seq_along(x)){
                        index<-(i+1-range_moving_avg):i
                        index<-index[index>=0]
                        output[i]<-mean(x[index])
                }
                
        }
        output
        }
```

```
moving_avg(1:10, 7)

 [1] 1.0 1.5 2.0 2.5 3.0 3.5 4.0 5.0 6.0 7.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method using for loop

```
rol_mn <- function(x, n){
  r <- numeric()
  for(i in seq_along(x)){
    r[i] <- mean(x[seq(i-n+1, i, 1)[seq(i-n+1, i, 1) > 0]])
  }
  return(r)
}

> rol_mn(1:10, 7)
 [1] 1.0 1.5 2.0 2.5 3.0 3.5 4.0 5.0 6.0 7.0
```